# Meteor-AngularJS Custom Registration interface

Tags: angularjs, meteor, authentication, registration

Initially, I was using the basic accounts package MeteorJS came up with for my users to sign in but I decided I wanted to change it into a custom interface but I'm just having a little difficulty finding any sort of tutorial that is relevant to using Meteor with AngularJS to develop a registration/login interface. I've been looking online for hours still haven't found anything. Found tutorials using blaze but I'm not using blaze in my MeteorJS app.

So I thought I'd ask on stackoverflow, if anyone knew any good resources of how to accomplish this and/or any guidance/advice that can help me out.
Thanks!